# Identificate an object by the camera and react

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Let's assume that the camera is turned into a wall and all it sees is white. Once I turn off the light on my room the camera will see black.

I would like to know how can I react to such a change, is there any kind of a listener?or other way to do that?

Comment: You should start googling for "Computer vision" topics. Not an issue that can be solved in a few lines.

Comment: I didn't ask for "few lines" to do that, a reference or an explanation would be appreciated. I know java and also how to mix it with the android platform but I never worked with the camera classes.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the grayscale response from the camera (kind of what I am doing with my app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only wanting to detect brightness as in the example you gave, you might want to look at the "Light Sensor". A lot (most) android devices have a light sensor for adjusting the brightness of the screen. Try looking here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Comment: Here is the guy that I looked for! thanks for your replay, just a question.. in case that the camera is seeing something (we both don't know what) and a man with a white t-shirt is passing through the camera. The "Light Sensor" will detect it?

Comment: It might detect the light reflected off his shirt, but I doubt it would be a very accurate detector. You'd need to experiment with it, sometimes these things can be surprising. It does sound like you want a motion detector.. fortunately that is usually a little simpler than full computer vision. You might want to look here: https://code.google.com/p/android-motion-detection/